# Is it normal to use in the function some variable with the same name as it function?

Tags: javascript, variables, naming

Is it normal to use in the function some variable with the same name as it function?

```js
const sum = function(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    sum += arr[i]; 
  return sum;
};
```

This code works fine without any warnings. But I'm curious can it lead to any trouble?

Comment: It is generally not a good idea, as it can create some confusion. Generally its a good idea to have separate names no matter what you do.

Comment: Your variables are scoped to your function, it's fine

Comment: If you do that, you will not able to make recursive functions

Comment: aptly! @graille

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally bad practice to "shadow" variable names. It can cause confusion about what's being referenced if you aren't careful.

In this example, there isn't a major downside. Consider though if later you decided to make the function recursive. If you tried to call `sum` from within itself, you'd get an error that `sum` isn't a function, because it's finding the inner variable `sum`, not the function. That's not a major issue, but it's a good idea to write code that is less likely to break in weird ways in the future. You never know what changes you might make later on.

Comment: While this is an example that doesn't make good sense for shadowing, the practice is hardly "bad practice", in general. Oftentimes, it is leveraged to create more efficient and dynamic code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I can't say I've ever heard of that. How would shadowing a name lead to more efficient code?

Comment: By hiding a variable, you can create variations of original code without having to rewrite an entire code base.

Comment: While I dislike shadowing, and even wish more languages would prohibit it, I would stop short of calling it a bad practice. People use those terms too casually, IMO.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That strikes me as a brittle was to set things up. You could create an answer defending it though, as I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I've never relied on shadowing in the way you describe.

Comment: @SkinnyPete I did hedge with "generally"; I'm certainly not stating an absolute. Seems contradictory though to want something to be banned, but not consider it bad practice.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: You a lawyer or a politician? **;-)** I think preventing shadowing lends itself to good design, but I just wouldn't call it "bad" when utilized. I also think strong type systems are better design for a language, but I wouldn't call dynamic typing "bad".

Comment: Hiding/Shadowing is a common feature in many modern programming languages. Like any feature, it should be used when it makes sense and not just because you "can". As I said, using it in conjunction with derived types make a more flexible (not brittle) design. Not being able to "override" a variable is what makes code brittle.

Comment: @SkinnyPete No lol. I lean more towards it being bad, but like with `goto`, it *could* be used appropriately. I still can't say I've ever seen shadowing used to any benefit though. To me it's always just been a question of whether it's neutral or harmful given a certain situation. I would say in general though, it has the potential to cause more harm than good. I would like to see an example of shadowing being used to some benefit though, as I honestly can't see how it would be beneficial.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't think overriding a method (if that's what you're referring to) would be considered shadowing.

Comment: Well, I must admit that I can't remember a time where I *needed* shadowing, but certainly have encountered bugs due to it, so you may have a point. I think Scott may be using the term "brittle" in a sense more like that where I'd use the term "friction", as is often used by Jonathan Blow in his language design talks, if you've followed him.

Comment: @Carcigenicate No, I'm not talking about overloading a method. Hiding is sometimes also referred to as overloading or shadowing.